# How does Go import Path works in versioned packages

Tags: go

I got kinda curious about how does Golang resolves named imports.

In example here, I got Echo as a package for my app.

```golang
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
)

func main() {
    e := echo.New()
    e.GET("/", func(c echo.Context) error {
        return c.String(http.StatusOK, "Hello, World!")
    })
    e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":1323"))
}
```

As seen on the `import` line, Echo is actually being referenced by it's "v4" version, but Go can resolve as "echo".
I've dug around Echo's Repo and couldn't find anything explicit on how does Go can resolve this.

PS: On the past I've used it with an alias, such as:

```golang
...
import (
    echo "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
)
...
```

but that seems to be a workaround.

Comment: The name of the package never has to correspond to the import path, it only does so by convention. For major versions, see the docs here https://go.dev/ref/mod#major-version-suffixes. Most formatting tools will add the package name to the import line automatically for clarity, even if it matches the actual package name.

Comment: The package is always referred to by the name in its `package` directive. This is entirely independent of its import path, which is what's in the `import` directive, but by convention the package name is the last or next-to-last (if the last is a version) part of the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line of a Go file declares the package name using the `package` directive. This is the name that `import` resolves to when it is not an aliased import. You can use aliased imports when you need to disambiguate between multiple packages that have the same package name but different import paths.

The `go.mod` file keeps the import path of the Go package (for `echo` that is `github.com/labstack/echo/v4`). As JimB said, the package name does not need to correspond to the import path, it only does so by convention.

[rsc.io/quote](https://rsc.io/quote) (source code at https://github.com/rsc/quote) explains Go package versioning and imports. You can also check these [blog posts](https://research.swtch.com/vgo) by Russ Cox explaining package versioning in Go.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response and references. I've never published a Go Package with major convention, so that's why I had some questions about it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you import a package, the name will be the **package name** not the **folder name**.

In your case, as shown in the picture, the folder name is `v4` but the package name is `echo`, so it will be resolved as `echo`.

[image: echo import]

It's a good and recommended convention to use the same package name as your folder name,

But folder versioning for major releases is known and valid.